# WSO2 APIManager 1.10 - Error getting hybrid roles from filter : %

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I Try create a user at store and assing a role for it. After 5 minutos, a receive the message below .I can't start the APIMAnager. The browser now shows  "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL".

Error at Log:

```
 o2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
 TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-01 16:42:18,750] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} -  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while getting hybrid roles from filter : % {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy}
 TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-01 16:42:18,759] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Error occurred while getting hybrid roles from filter : % {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
 org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
  at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminStub.java:3054)
  at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminClient.java:154)
  at org.apache.jsp.user.view_002droles_jsp._jspService(view_002droles_jsp.java:235)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
  at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
  at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
  at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:640)
  at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:356)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
  at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
  at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
  at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
  at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Before It, I changed the LDAP configurarion. I changed the "User Entry Object Class" from "person" to "posixAccount" and "User Search Filter" from  "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=?))" to "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=?))"

I did not change "Default Realm Name": "WSO2.ORG"

Comment: Have you changed the default user store? Or any other configurations?

Comment: Yes, I added a LDAP user store.

Comment: can you update your question with userstore configs?